# Taking second last observed row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas. I know how to use drop_duplicates and take the last observed row in a dataframe. Is there any way that I can use it to take only second last observed. Or any other way of doing it. 
For example:
I would like to go from

`df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})` to

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2],'B':[2,5]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you'll group the data by the duplicate column , then check the length of group , if the length of group is greater than or equal 2 this mean that you can slice the second element of group , if the group has a length of one which mean that this value is not duplicated , then take index `0` which is the only element in the grouped data

```
df.groupby(df['A']).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1] if len(x) >= 2 else x.iloc[0])
```

Comment: If the group is length 2 then presumably the value a `.iloc[0]` is the right value to preserve.

Comment: as per the question `Is there any way that I can use it to take only second last observed` so why we would take the first element for the group with length of `2`

Comment: It seems to me that in a group comprising two observations, the second last observed (or penultimate) is also the first observation.

Comment: I got your point you mean that he wants to retrieve the value which is before the last one ... But I don't think he meant that

Answer (score 1):

The first answer I think was on the right track, but possibly not quite right. I have extended your data to include 'A' groups with two observations, and an 'A' group with one observation, for the sake of completeness.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2, 3, 3, 4],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9]})

def user_apply_func(x):
    if len(x) == 2:
        return x.iloc[0]
    if len(x) > 2:
        return x.iloc[-2]
    return 

df.groupby('A').apply(user_apply_func)

Out[7]: 
    A   B
A        
1   1   2
2   2   5
3   3   7
4 NaN NaN
```

For your reference the `apply` method automatically passes the data frame as the first argument.

Also, as you are always going to be reducing each group of data to a single observation you could also use the `agg` method (aggregate). `apply` is more flexible in terms of the length of the sequences that can be returned whereas `agg` must reduce the data to a single value.

```
df.groupby('A').agg(user_apply_func)
```